# jQuery does not show response after submitting data by JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with jQuery showing response when submitting data by using JSON.

this is my HTML

```
<input required="" width="100%" name="category_id" id="category_id" 
class="form-control">

<input required="" width="100%" name="agent_id" id="agent_id" 
class="form-control">

<input required="" width="100%" name="year" id="year" 
class="form-control">

<button type="button" onclick="historyForm()" title="fetch history"> 
view</button>

<div id="ajax-content">
</div>
```

Here is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function historyForm() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?staff/fetch_history',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            category_id: $("#category_id").val(),
            agent_id: $("#agent_id").val(),
            year: $("#year").val(),
        },
        success: function (response) {
            jQuery('#ajax-content').html(response);
        }
    });
   }

  </script>
```

Here is my controller

```
function fetch_history()
{
    $response = array();
    $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
    $agent_id = $_POST["agent_id"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $page_data['category_id']    =   $category_id;
    $page_data['agent_id']    =   $agent_id;
    $page_data['year']    =   $year;
    $response = $this->load->view('backend/staff/history_result' , 
 $page_data);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I don't see any response and any error, but when I try to write the `$page_data` manually let say `$year = '2018', $agent_id = 1 and $category_id = 2` I get the response.

What can be the problem?

Comment: what you get if write in javascript: `console.log(response)` in `success` method ?

Comment: Also `url` is ok in ajax ?

Comment: @Snake , thanks for your comment. `console.log(response)` also show nothing.

Comment: The url from ajax is correct ? The `$_POST[...]` give you  right info ?

Comment: @Snakes, when I assuming that `$year = '2018'`, `$category_id = 1` and `$agent_id = 2` I get the response well. But when I use JSON to submit the result nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to send HTML page through json...  change `dataType` from `$.ajax` like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?staff/fetch_history',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',  // here is the change
    data: {
        category_id: $("#category_id").val(),
        agent_id: $("#agent_id").val(),
        year: $("#year").val(),
    },
    success: function (response) {
        jQuery('#ajax-content').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Snake, everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code in your controller

```
function fetch_history()
{
    $response = array();
    $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
    $agent_id = $_POST["agent_id"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $page_data['category_id']    =   $category_id;
    $page_data['agent_id']    =   $agent_id;
    $page_data['year']    =   $year;
    $response = $this->load->view('backend/staff/history_result' , 
 $page_data);

    $newResponse = ['result'=>$response];

    echo json_encode($newResponse);
}
```

And Get the result in success with

> response.result

Check if it helps..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but also nothing is displayed for newResponse

Comment: can you show the data in  $response = $this->load->view('backend/staff/history_result' , 
 $page_data);

Comment: Try this:

1) remove "dataType: 'json'" from js and add "response = $.parseJSON(response);" into success

Comment: I got the following error `VM417:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (index.php?staff/history:999)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)`  and the changes are `success: function (response) {
    response = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(response);
    jQuery('#ajax-content').html(response);
   }`

Comment: you cannot send HTML in json !

Comment: yes.. your json should like this {"result": "<p>I'm the markup</p>"}. so try to send your html as string in response.

Comment: But why when I assuming that `$year = '2018'`, `$category_id = 1` and `$agent_id = 2` every thing work fine?

Comment: Thanks to @Prashant Patil, because your efforts were the source for the detection of the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the TRUE as the 3rd parameter in your page view so its being output directly instead of being saved into $response.

So change this line

```
$response = $this->load->view('backend/staff/history_result',$page_data);
```

Adding the 3rd parameter of TRUE, which prevents it outputting to the screen directly which will appear in your response.

```
$response = $this->load->view('backend/staff/history_result',$page_data, TRUE);
```